# Custom UIViewController subclass only shows a black screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have created a subclass of UIViewController called LoginController. I have a LoginController.xib file that contains a view controller with a few elements in it. I have set the class of the view controller to LoginController and I have set my Main Interface to LoginController. Upon launching my app, I see my splash screen, followed by a pure black screen. My LoginController class just has the default code like so

```
class LoginController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Xib file is not loaded, can you post code of LoginController initialization? Why don't you use storyboard?

Comment: The code I posted is all of the LoginController code.I'm not using a storyboard because (at least for this portion) it doesn't seem to match what I'm doing. This is a login screen so when the login button is pressed, it should validate and then go to the next screen or display an error. If I have a segue from the login button to the next screen, I can validate in prepareForSegue, but I don't see any way to stop the segue if the validation fails.

Comment: You can perform segue only after a successful validation or use shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier method to stop segue transition if validation fails. That's the right approach. If you don't want to use it anyway, you should load xib file in viewDidLoad method, or manually start LoginViewController from AppDelegate using initWithNibName method

Answer (score 1):

I just created a new xcode project. My results are totally normal. So I guess it's because you are not setting the LoginController.xib as the initial xib to load?

Comment: The screen does not turn white when I do this.

Comment: Have you set the LoginController as initial View Controller when App launches? or can you add some print line under `super.viewDidLoad` to check if LoginController is loaded or not.

Comment: @robz I just created a new xcode project. My results are totally normal. So I guess it's because you are not setting the LoginController.xib as the initial xib to load?